# How do I get the unique values of a column?

Tags: cassandra

I tried to create with partition keys, but I just want to show 1 [details] column, not the sysid/library.

```
 sysid | item_name | details   | library    | timestamp
-------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------------
 001   | book1     | color     | library-KR | 2023-07-14 08:50
 002   | book2     | color     | library-JP | 2023-07-14 08:52
 003   | book3     | font      | library-KR | 2023-07-15 10:50
 004   | book1     | thickness | library-JP | 2023-07-15 11:00
 005   | book1     | color     | library-KR | 2023-07-16 08:34
 006   | book2     | papertype | library-JP | 2023-07-16 09:45
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS library_book (
   sysid UUID ,
   item_name text,
   details text,
   library text,
   timestamp TIMESTAMP,
   PRIMARY KEY (sysid,library,details)
)
```

I want to get the only unique data value for `details` column WHERE `library='library-KR'`

query I tried:

```
SELECT details FROM library_book WHERE library=library-KR;

 details
---------
 color
 font
 color
```

When i try to use DISTINCT , I get the following error:

```
[Invalid query] message="SELECT DISTINCT queries must request \
  all the partition key columns (missing sysid)"
```

desired output:

```
 details
---------
 color
 font
```

I am new to CassandraDB keys. Please advice which type of keys I should use. (partition keys/clustering keys/..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Cassandra, you want to build your tables based on your query.

If you want to filter by `library`..it will be your partition key. As it is not enough to
get unicity or order the result you will add a couple of clustering column (order matter).

By convention it is good the name the table to describe how your are suppose to query it. Here it would be `book_by_library`. I do not think you need a timestamp for this query or unicity. Still, you can change `sysid` to be a `timeuuid`.

Your table becomes:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book_by_library (
   library  text,
   details  text,
   sysid     timeuuid,
   item_name text,
   PRIMARY KEY ((library),details, sysid)
);
```

Insert a few records:

```sql
insert into book_by_library (sysid,item_name,details,library)
values (now(),'book1','color','library-KR');
insert into book_by_library (sysid,item_name,details,library)
values (now(),'book2','color','library-JP');
insert into book_by_library (sysid,item_name,details,library)
values (now(),'book3','font','library-KR');
insert into book_by_library (sysid,item_name,details,library)
values (now(),'book1','thickness','library-JP');
insert into book_by_library (sysid,item_name,details,library)
values (now(),'book1','color','library-KR');
insert into book_by_library (sysid,item_name,details,library)
values (now(),'book2','papertype','library-JP');
```

If you test

```sql
SELECT details FROM book_by_library
WHERE library='library-KR';
```

You still get 2 records for `color`.

```sql
 details
---------
   color
   color
    font
```

You cannot use `DISTINCT` on `details` as it is not a partition key..but you can use a trick with `group by`

```sql
SELECT details FROM book_by_library  
WHERE library='library-KR'  
GROUP BY library, details;
```

You got now your expected output:

```sql
 details
---------
   color
    font
```

To know more acout data modelling check the free course DS220 on academy.datastax.com

Answer (score 0):

In Cassandra data modelling, the primary principle is to design a table for EVERY application query.

The table in your schema is partitioned by `sysid` so you cannot filter by `library`:

```
    PRIMARY KEY (sysid,library,details)
```

Since your application query (in plain English) is:

> Retrieve the distinct details of books in a library

you need to have `library` as the partition key and `details` as the clustering key. Since `sysid` is the only column that contains unique values, we need to add it as the clustering key. The resulting schema should look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE books_by_library (
    library text,
    details text,
    sysid text,
    PRIMARY KEY (library, details, sysid)
)
```

Notice that I didn't bother storing `item_name` or `timestamp` in this table since it is not required by the application query.

Using your sample data for inspiration, let's assume the new table contains the following:

```
 library | details   | sysid
---------+-----------+-------
 JP      | color     | 002
 JP      | thickness | 004  
 JP      | papertype | 006  
 KR      | color     | 001  
 KR      | font      | 003  
 KR      | color     | 005
```

You can then query the table with a filter on `library` and using the `GROUP BY` clause to group the rows making `details` appear distinct as a side-effect:

```
SELECT details FROM books_by_library
    WHERE library = 'KR'
    GROUP BY library, details
```